# Java dock JToolBar to a different JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, docking, jtoolbar

For a GUI i'm working on I need a JToolBar to be able to dock into more than one JPanel.

Because I have multiple toolbars inside a JPanel in the BorderLayout.NORTH position, I can't add the toolbar directly to the main JPanel and so I don't get access the EAST and WEST positions of the BorderLayout.

I found this thread [Transfer jtoolbar from one jpanel to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266332/transfer-jtoolbar-from-one-jpanel-to-another) but haven't been able to use the BasicToolBarUI.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: The toolbar has been designed to dock with the BorderLayout, docking it anywhere else would require you to manage the layout of the container you're trying to dock to. What exactly are you trying to do?  You could wrap your over panels in panels that use BorderLayout...